# Does a std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>> with each individual unique_ptr vector item cache-line aligned make sense in order to avoid false sharing?

Tags: c++, boost, stdvector, unique-ptr, memory-alignment

Assuming such vector is `std::vector<T, boost::alignment::aligned_allocator<T, 64>>` would be read/write accessed by several cores concurrently and having it allocated on a per-core basis (i.e. vector index 0 used by the CPU core 0 only, 1 by the core 1, and so on), if one wants to avoid false-sharing, the underlying `T` here would have to be declared as either `alignas(64)` or just ensuring to have it properly padded to a standard x86 cache line size (i.e. 64 bytes). But what if the vector's `T`  is `std::unique_ptr<U>`? Does the same still hold and make sense, i.e. each vector item - in this case `std::unique_ptr` - required to be 64 bytes in size?

Comment: unique_ptr is just a pointer. The answer depends on how the values it points to were obtained. A default heap allocator aligns on 16 bytes, so not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to modify the pointer, then yes, you should ensure the pointers themselves are aligned. However, if the pointers are never changed while your parallel code is running, then they don't have to (it's fine to share read-only data among threads even if they share cache lines). But then you have to make sure `U` is correctly aligned.

Note: don't assume 64 bytes cache line size, use [`std::hardware_destuctive_interference_size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/hardware_destructive_interference_size) instead.

Comment: The `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<U>>` himself would be fully constructed before spawning per-core threads that would dereference it later for their own processing, and never modified again. The only write access would be on the underlying pointed `U`, which btw is declared as `alignas(64)`. So this means that I wouldn't have to cache-align the unique_ptrs themselves, correct?

Comment: @pa5h1nh0 Correct.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer ;) . Btw, as `U` is declared with `alignas`, do I also have to use a custom allocator for `std::unique_ptr` so it'll allocate cache-line aligned memory, or that's not necessary?

Comment: Yes, you do need the memory for `U` to be allocated cache-aligned. However, `std::unique_ptr` itself does not allocate memory, it only *stores* a pointer, so it doesn't take a custom allocator as a parameter. You have to provide `std::unique_ptr` with a pointer to properly aligned memory yourself.

Comment: I see, sort of a `make_unique_aligned` and internally allocating with `new` taking the alignment size.